# Ng Show only works on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-material

The scenario I am working on is when a user is signed in, they will see a separate list of navigation options and buttons than a user that is not signed in.

To do this, I am using NgShow to show/hide these elements. The issue I am facing is that these elements wont show/hide until I do a refresh on the page.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

CTRL

```
angular.module('core').controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', '$mdSidenav', 'Authentication', 'Users', 'Menus',
function($scope, $mdSidenav, Authentication, Users, Menus) {
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;
    $scope.user = Authentication.user;
    $scope.isCollapsed = false;

    $scope.toggleCollapsibleMenu = function() {
        $scope.isCollapsed = !$scope.isCollapsed;
    };

    // Collapsing the menu after navigation
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
        $scope.isCollapsed = false;
    });

    $scope.toggleSidenav = function(menuId) {
            $mdSidenav('left').toggle();
            };
}
```

])

HTML / VIEW

```
<md-button aria-label="Search" data-ng-click="showSearch = !showSearch" data-ng-show="user">
    <ng-md-icon style="fill:#fff;" icon="search"></ng-md-icon>
  </md-button>

  <md-button data-ng-show="!user" aria-label="Sign In" data-ng-href="#!/signin">
    <ng-md-icon style="fill:#fff;" icon="login"></ng-md-icon><span style="padding-left:10px;color:#fff;">Sign In</span>
  </md-button>
  <md-button data-ng-show="!user" aria-label="Sign Up" data-ng-href="#!/signup">
    <ng-md-icon style="fill:#fff;" icon="local_florist"></ng-md-icon><span style="padding-left:10px;color:#fff;">Sign Up</span>
  </md-button>
```

Comment: What is `Authentication`?

Comment: I am using meanjs to generate parts of my app. meanjs uses passport and oauth for authorization and signup/signin. Authentication is what allows the user to be authenticated. @tymeJV

Comment: Can you post what it actually is?

Comment: I was having issues with ng-show and the `!` character. I changed it to ng-hide without the ! and it seems to work better...

Comment: could you try the `data-ng-show="authentication.user"` will update everytime

Comment: @PankajParkar it worked!

But it doesn't work with Admin roles.....

<div data-ng-show="user.roles == 'admin'">
          <md-subheader>Admin</md-subheader>
          <md-divider></md-divider>
          <md-item>
            <a>
              <md-item-content md-ink-ripple layout="row" layout-align="start center">
                <div class="inset">
                  <ng-md-icon icon="keyboard_alt"></ng-md-icon>
                </div>
                <div class="inset">admin
                </div>
              </md-item-content>
            </a>
          </md-item>
        </div>

Comment: @PankajParkar I tried data-ng-show="authentication.user.roles == 'admin' and it completely hides the element, even after refresh. If i just use user.roles, it will show after I refresh the page.

Comment: @PankajParkar any idea?

Comment: @MichaelChristopherMartire what `authentication.user.roles` contains? is it array?

Comment: This is the scope object:

authentication:
user:
_id: "55c030060b122e97a49d473b"
displayName: "MICHAEL GRAHAM"
provider: "local"
username: "admin"
__v: 0
created: "2015-08-04T03:22:46.941Z"
roles:
0: "admin"


When I use authentication.user.roles it completely hides the element, even after refresh